# Error: Cannot find module 'color-support' windows globally npm 8.15

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm running windows 10 on my machine and have just updated to the newest NPM version 8.15, after updating, none of my npm commands work, I can't even run `npm --version` or `npm install`, seems like NPM have broken something in this version potentially, how can I resolve this?

```
(node:8916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'color-support'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\has-color.js
```

[image]